# If $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-ax+b}{x-1} = 5$ then find $a+b$

Tags: limits

> If
> $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-ax+b}{x-1} = 5$$
> then find $a+b$

The solution which I have says that  $x-1$ tends to $0$. Therefore numerator $x^2 - ax + b$ must tend to $0$ **because the limit exists**.

My query is: why it is written, that limit exists so numerator of tend to $0$.

Comment: Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "*What is meant by limit exists*"... This should have been included in your book, notes, etc... as a basic definition.  I can't believe you haven't been exposed to this already before having been given this question.

Comment: The existence of a limit is part of the definition of a limit. I suggest you go back to the textbook you are using and re-read the chapter on limits.

Comment: See [Limit (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)) on wikipedia or see your textbook.  The handwavy description of the definition of a limit... your limit as $x$ approaches $1$ is equal to $5$ means that "*if we get 'really close' to $x=1$ we get 'really close' to the expression equaling $5$.*"  The formal definition is written using $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s.  The punchline for your problem should be that your expression should be of the form $\dfrac{(x-1)(x+4)}{(x-1)}$, this way the $(x-1)$'s in the numerator and denominator will effectively "cancel."

Comment: Do remember that $\dfrac{(x-1)(x+4)}{(x-1)}$ is equal to $(x+4)$ for all $x$ different than $1$... however it is distinct from $(x+4)$ since $(x+4)$ is defined at $x=1$ while $\dfrac{(x-1)(x+4)}{(x-1)}$ is undefined at $x=1$.  See [removable discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity).

Comment: @5xum thanks for the edit. I know what is meant by existence of limit. My question was why is it given as an argument for numerator to tend to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say that $f$ approaches the limit $l$ near $c$ if we can make $f(x)$ as close to $l$ as we like by requiring that $x$ be sufficiently close to, but unequal to, $c$. We write this as $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=l$. If the statement $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=l$ is false for every $l\in\Bbb{R}$ (that is, if $f$ does not approach any limit near $c$), then we say that the limit does not exist.

It can shown that if $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)\neq0$, then
$$
\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \ \text{does not exist.}
$$
Hence, in order for the limit to exist, it must be the case that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=0$. In your example, we need to find numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim_{x \to 1}(x^2-ax+b)=0$, and that make the overall limit equal to $5$.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why they have downvoted?

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @KushSingh: I'm glad I could help. If you know any question, then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For the limit to exist, numerator should also be zero.

$\implies 1-a+b=0$

On applying L'Hopital rule,
$$\mathrm{\frac{2x-a}{1} = 5}$$ when x=1.
$$\implies 2-a =5 \implies a=-3$$
$$\implies b= -4$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^2-ax+b}{x-1}=x-a+1+\frac{b-a+1}{x-1}$$ and for the limit to exist, the numerator of the fraction must be zero.

Hence

$$\begin{cases}b-a+1=0,\\1-a+1=5.\end{cases}$$